# The number of increasing functions is equal to the number of n-tuple

Tags: combinatorics

Let $C_{p,n}$ be the group of the increasing function from $ [1,p]$ to $[1,n]$ (only integers). Prove that the cardinal of $C_{p,n}$ is equal to the number of n-tuple of integers verifying $x_1 + ... + x_n = p$. I did find a combinatoric method which is pretty long and I believe, clumsy. Any shorts and clear methods ?

Comment: Are you sure it's not $x_1+\dots+x_p=n$?

Comment: nope it's $x_1 + ... + x_n = p$

Comment: Now, I must be missing something. For $p>1$ and $n=1$, there is *no* increasing function from $\{1,\dots,p\}$ to $\{1\}$, but there is one $1$-tuple summing to $p$... did you mean non-decreasing?.

Comment: It's not strictly increasing function but just increasing, meaning that any  constant function would do it. I though increasing also meant that, just as decreasing would, so yeah basically non decreasing

Comment: I see. In English (and though I find this terminology odd at best), the term is *non-decreasing*. Increasing means strictly increasing.

Comment: yeah that's not the case in french, good to know !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

If $C_{p,n}^+$ denotes the set of *strictly* increasing functions from $\{1,\cdots,p\}$ to $\{1,\cdots,n\}$, then the map :

$$C_{p,n}\to C_{p,n+p-1}^+,\,f\mapsto[x\mapsto f(x)+x-1]$$

is a bijection.